# WCSessionDelegate: sessionDidBecomeInactive and sessionDidDeactivate have been marked unavailable, but are required

Tags: watchkit, swift3, xcode8, wcsession

I just converted a Swift 2 app to Swift 3, using the convert function of Xcode 8.

My code has a class marked as `WCSessionDelegate`.

In Swift 2 it compiled without the methods `sessionDidBecomeInactive` and `sessionDidDeactivate`.

If I compile the Swift 3 version, the compiler complains that my class does not conform to protocol `WCSessionDelegate`, which is apparently correct.
It then offers to insert stubs for both functions:

```
public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) { }  
public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) { }
```

After these stubs are inserted, these errors are reported:

```
Cannot override 'sessionDidBecomeInactive' which has been marked unavailable  
Cannot override 'sessionDidDeactivate' which has been marked unavailable
```

How can I fix this problem?

Comment: The class where you added the `deactivate` and `inactive` callbacks; is it compiled and used for both the iOS app and WatchKit extension?

Comment: @ccjensen: Yes, this class is shared.

Comment: @ccjensen: The problem exists also, if the class has only the watch extension as target.

Answer (score 47, accepted):

Because the delegate methods `sessionDidDeactivate` and `sessionDidBecomeInactive` are marked as unavailable on watchOS you will have to make the compiler ignore those pieces of code in the shared class. You can do so using the following preprocessor macro:

```
#if os(iOS)
public func sessionDidBecomeInactive(_ session: WCSession) { }  
public func sessionDidDeactivate(_ session: WCSession) {
    session.activate()
}
#endif
```

Please also note I added the `activate` call in the `sessionDidDeactivate` call. This is to re-activate the session on the phone when the user has switched from one paired watch to second paired one. Calling it like this assumes that you have no other threads/part of your code that needs to be given time before the switch occurs. For more information on supporting the quick watch switching you should take a look at the Apple [sample code](https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/QuickSwitch/Introduction/Intro.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40016647)

Comment: Thanks for your efforts, but the suggested code improvements did not eliminate the compiler errors, see me edit above.

Comment: Thanks, bashed my against this one all morning.

Comment: "Function-like macro 'os' is not defined"